# CSR - One function for every field in a View?

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering

We all know how to define **one** template function for **one** field.

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  Templates: {
    Fields: {
           "[fieldname]": {
               View: myCustomFunction,
           }
       },
  });
```

Can I use **one** template function for **every** field displayed in the View?
*I do not know the internal fieldnames upfront and I prefer not to loop over the ctx object*